# Can we regard a A-module $M$ as a $A/radA$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional algebra over a field, and $M$ be a finitely generated module of $A$. Can we regard $M$ as a $A/radA$ module with module structure inherited from $M$ as a $A$ module?

For example, we define $(a+radA)m=am$ , where "am" is aleady defined as "am" in A-module $M$.

My teacher's answer to this question is NO, but I think this satisfies the definition of module.

Comment: ony if $(rad A) M = 0$

Comment: if the module is simple then you can do what you said as @Exodd pointed out

Comment: The problem is that your product is not well defined in general: you need that if $a+rad(A)=a'+rad(A)$, then $am=a'm$ for any $m\in M$. This is equivalent to ask that $rad(A)M=0$.

Comment: There is of course another possibility, which is when $A\to A/\mathrm{rad}A$ splits. Then there is an embedding $A/\mathrm{rad}A\to A$ and we can use restrictions of scalars. For example, every module over the path algebra of a quiver is a tuple of vector spaces supported at the vertices, together with linear maps between them. Forgetting the linear maps gives a module for a product of fields, which is a subalgebra isomorphic to the quotient $kQ/\mathrm{rad}kQ$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your teacher is right.

How would you define $(a+\operatorname{rad}A)m$? If you define it as $am$, you need that, when $a+\operatorname{rad}A=b+\operatorname{rad}A$, then also
$$
am=bm
$$
which is precisely the needed condition, namely

> for every $r\in\operatorname{rad}A$ and every $m\in M$, $rm=0$

For instance, consider the localization $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ of $\mathbb{Z}$ at the prime ideal $(p)$, where $p$ is any prime. Then
$$
\operatorname{rad}\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}=p\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}
$$
and
$$
\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}/\operatorname{rad}\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}\cong \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}
$$
But, clearly, $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ itself cannot be considered as a module over the quotient ring modulo the radical.

You can easily find examples for algebras over fields, using a similar idea, namely, local rings.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that the annihilator of $M$ is the ideal $$\operatorname{Ann}(M)=\{a\in A\mid aM=0\}.$$

You can always consider $M$ as an $A/\operatorname{Ann}(M)$-module, and more generally an $A/I$-module as long as $I\subseteq \operatorname{Ann}(M)$. Your construction is well-defined as long as $\operatorname{Rad}(A)\subseteq \operatorname{Ann}(M)$, i.e. $\operatorname{Rad}(A)M=0.$